# Make images inline (blocks) in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, inline

I have 6 images in my website embedded inside a ul list and a div tag as shown belows :

```
<div id="left_box">
      <input type="textbox" id="myDiv" class="resizedTextbox" display="none" readonly/>
      <ul id="thumbnails">
         <li>
            <div id="main_image_holder">
               <div class="photocontainer" width="100%">
                  <img class="photo" id="website1" src="photo1.jpg" alt="Click to see enlarged image" />
                  <br><br>
                  <figcaption><a href="#website1Modal"/>BooksForGeeks</a></figcaption>
               </div>
         </li>
         <li>
         <div class="photocontainer">
         <img class="photo" id="website2" name="website2" src="aperture.png" alt="Click to see enlarged image" />
         <br><br>
         <figcaption><a href="#website2Modal"/>Aperture Laboratories</a></figcaption>
         </div> 
         </li>
         <li>
         .
         .
         .
         </li>
      </ul>
      </div>


  The CSS that I have used to display the images is : 


#left_box {
margin-top:60px;
padding-top:10px;
width:250px;
margin-left:20px;
padding-bottom:10px;
float:left;
}
#thumbnails {
list-style-type: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
float:left;
}

#thumbnails li {
margin:0;
padding:0;
float:left;
}

.photocontainer {
width:130px;
height:100px;
margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #000;
float:left;
}
.photo {
position:relative;
width:120px;
height:90px;
top:4px;
left:4px;
border: 1px solid #666666;
}
img{
    display:inline;
}
```

Now, 
the image list appears on the leftmost side , one below the other. 
However, **I wish to display 3 images horizontally as one row and the remaining three in the same manner as second row. **

How can I achieve this ?

I tried to use css as :

```
img{
display:inline;
}
```

However, that did not work. 
Can anyone tell me where I am wrong ? 
This is how curretly my webpage looks like : 
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the photocontainer width to 120px, and you want to place 3 images next to each other, this would result in taking up 390px. The #left_box is only 250px in width, so you should either adjust that to 390, or reduce your photocontainer width.

Adding / adjusting the following CSS would work:

```
#left_box {
    width:390px;
}

#thumbnails li {
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

See a working jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/18Lmbs7e/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot ;) 
Liked your calculations and it worked completely fine.